# AngularJS data-ng-controller doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I could not figure out why the following code doesn't work at all. Frankly, It looks alright to me. Is there any idea?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">
    <head>
        <title>Using AngularJS to create a simple Controller</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-ng-controller="simpleController">
            <ul>
                <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers">{{ cust.Name | uppercase }} - {{ cust.City | lowercase }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <script
                type="text/javascript"
                src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            function simpleController($scope) {
                $scope.customers = [
                    { Name: "Dave Jones",  City: "Phoenix" }
                    , { Name: "Jamie Riley", City: "Atlanta" }
                    , { Name: "Heedy Walhin", City: "Chandler" }
                    , { Name: "Thomas Winter", City: "Seattle" }
                ];
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### It is to do with the version of angular you are using.

Earlier versions of Angular allowed the ability to assign controller functions to the global scope like you did.
Then this ability was removed from angular.
There are still alot of tutorials around that reference this older style however.

See this **demo** - http://jsbin.com/fowamutoli/1/edit

I have replaced with angular legacy and your code runs.

So in the future you need to declare an angular module and register your controller against it.
i.e.

```
<html data-ng-app="app">


 <script>

        var app = angular.module('app', []).  
            controller('simpleController', function ($scope) {
                $scope.customers = [
                    { Name: "Dave Jones",  City: "Phoenix" }
                    , { Name: "Jamie Riley", City: "Atlanta" }
                    , { Name: "Heedy Walhin", City: "Chandler" }
                    , { Name: "Thomas Winter", City: "Seattle" }
                ];
            });
  </script>
```

Comment: Was this answer useful to you? - if it helped, you can accept it - that way others will be able to learn from your question

Comment: Hi Michael, it's exactly the version issue. Many thanks for your help

Comment: Thank you, this was totally not obvious to a newb.

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

try replacing your data-ng-app to ng-app="myApp", see if it works. :) with the following snippet.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('simpleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.customers = [
                { Name: "Dave Jones",  City: "Phoenix" }
                , { Name: "Jamie Riley", City: "Atlanta" }
                , { Name: "Heedy Walhin", City: "Chandler" }
                , { Name: "Thomas Winter", City: "Seattle" }
            ];
}]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
    <head>
        <title>Using AngularJS to create a simple Controller</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="simpleController">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="cust in customers">{{ cust.Name | uppercase }} - {{ cust.City | lowercase }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var myApp = angular.module( "MyApp", [] );
            myApp.controller("simpleController", function( $scope )
            {
                $scope.customers = [
                    { Name: "Dave Jones",  City: "Phoenix" }
                    , { Name: "Jamie Riley", City: "Atlanta" }
                    , { Name: "Heedy Walhin", City: "Chandler" }
                    , { Name: "Thomas Winter", City: "Seattle" }
                ];
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rv7r7nv7/